# Starting process is not always starting

Tags: c#, .net, process, process.start

I have the following function:

```
public static void ExecuteNewProcess(string fileToExecute, Action<string> writeToConsole)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileToExecute);
    Process processToExecute = new Process();

    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    processToExecute.StartInfo = startInfo;

    if (!File.Exists(fileToExecute))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found for execution");
    }

    if (processToExecute.Start())
    {
        Thread.Sleep(6000);
        Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();

        if (IsProcessOpen(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileToExecute)))
        {
            writeToConsole(fileToExecute + " launched successfully...");
        }
        else
        {
            writeToConsole(fileToExecute + " started but not found.");
            throw new Exception("Application started butnot found running...Delay = 6000, File Name = " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileToExecute));               
        }

    }
    else
    {
        writeToConsole("Error Launching application: " + fileToExecute);
        throw new Exception("Application did not launch " + fileToExecute);
    }

}

private static bool IsProcessOpen(string name)
{

    foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
    {

        if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name))
        {

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

So the problem is that sometimes my application that I am trying to start with this function is not starting (It starts about 80% of the time). However I do go through the part of the code that checks to make sure it started and outputs as such. I am not sure why it is not starting. I double click the application when I see it doesnt start to make sure its a valid exe. It always is and starts fine. I have also tried using the shell and not using the shell. No difference.

I am thinking that processToExecute is getting cleaned up before the application has successfully started all the way. Just a guess though.

I appreciate your help in advance.

I put in a few sleeps to see if it was just happening too fast.

Comment: You can use Process.GetProcessesByName: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname.aspx

Comment: Also, instead of checking if Process.GetProcesses.. returns any process with the same name, can you just check if processToExecute .HasExited after it has started? If comparing against the current running processes, you might also want to use the Id of the process when searching  because you could have multiple processes running with the same name

Comment: Also you probably want to ignore case when checking against the process name and use .Equals instead of .Contains:

bool exists = Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.ProcessName.Equals(processName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

Comment: @SeanP: When your application doesn't start but the method above sees otherwise, do a check with Task Manager. Is the process listed there? (...and as Misha recommends, certainly use a more robust technique for process identification; using Process.Id should be a good start.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason 20% of time your application don't show up when started by Process because of the time the application takes load before we see the user Interface

So their are two ways through which you might be able to achieve it

`1. start the process - > process.Start(); And then process.WaitForInputIdle();`

OR

```
 2. start the process - > process.Start(); And then  Thread.Sleep(1000);
    //make sure you give reasonable milliseconds
```

Comment: I have your second option implemented... check the code above.

if (processToExecute.Start())
    {
        Thread.Sleep(6000);

Comment: Oh yes :) did you try the first one

Comment: Ok I tried #1 and it didnt work. Actually I took the thread.sleeps out and it doesnt launch everytime now. I put WaitForInputIdle() in their place. I still got to the part of the code that checks and it does see the process as started. Just seems to die...

Comment: I am afraid seems like Thread.Sleep is the only way ahead... btw this is what i do my automation apps